# Case insensitive Array any() filter in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm migrating some code from SqlAlchemy 1.3 to SqlAlchemy 1.4 with Postgres 12. I found a query that looks like this:

```
session.query(Horse)
  .filter(Horse.nicknames.any("charlie", operator=ColumnOperators.ilike))
```

The type of the column `nicknames` is `Column(ARRAY(String(64)))`.

It seems to me that what this is doing is queryng any `Horse` whose one of their `nicknames` is  `charlie` in a case-insensitive (`ilike`) way.

This code seems to work fine in `SqlAlchemy==1.3.0` and fails in version `1.4.40` with the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.UnsupportedCompilationError:
Compiler <sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.psycopg2.PGCompiler_psycopg2 object at 0x7fce54c80f10>
can't render element of type <function ColumnOperators.ilike at 0x7fce92944280>
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/l7de)
```

What would be an equivalent way of doing this that works, ideally for both versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query seems to have broken in SQLAlchemy version 1.3.20<sup>*</sup>. In 1.3.0 it generated this SQL (aliases removed for clarity):

```sql
SELECT id, nicknames 
FROM horse
WHERE 'charlie' ILIKE ANY (nicknames)
```

The docs for [any](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.ARRAY.Comparator.any) mention that it has been superseded by [any_](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.any_), though it doesn't seem to have been formally deprecated. With this knowledge we can build an alternative that generates the same SQL:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
...
session.query(Horse).filter(
    sa.literal('able').ilike(sa.any_(Horse.nicknames))
)
```

or in 2.0-style:

```py
sa.select(Horse).where(
    sa.literal('charlie').ilike(sa.any_(Horse.nicknames))
)
```

---

<sup>*</sup> I don't see anything in the release notes regarding this change in behaviour, so it might be a regression, but at this stage it's probably better to go with the `any_` construct.

Comment: this is new for me so +1, also not OP, but I would like to know if one can also apply "[startswith](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnOperators.startswith)" (instead of ilike) using the same manner? eg: "any of the element starts with Foo"

Comment: @python_user the answers [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/228235/151124) would suggest no, or at least not easily.